# Replicate trigger code for various SObjects

Tags: apex, custom-object, customsetting, trigger

I have a requirement where I need same trigger code to fire after update on seven custom objects. Only the object name on trigger code would change.

Is there any way that I can put the whole trigger code as generic as a CSS file or in a custom setting text field and feed only object names wherever necessary?

Just to avoid writing same trigger code on different objects.

Please find my trigger code here where Account SObject would be replaced with other object names as I replicate the code.

**trigger:**

```
trigger AccountFieldupdate on Account (after update) {
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> trackedFields =     SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.alertengine.getFields();
if (trackedFields.isEmpty()) return;

List<Alert_vod__c> fieldChanges = new List<Alert_vod__c>();

List<string> apiNameList = new List<string>();        

if(Trigger.isUpdate){
for (Account aNew : trigger.new) {

Account aOld = trigger.oldmap.get(aNew.Id);

for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : trackedFields) {

String fieldName  = fsm.getFieldPath();
String fieldLabel = fsm.getLabel();

    if (!fieldName.contains('.')) {
if (aNew.get(fieldName) != aOld.get(fieldName)) {

String oldValue = String.valueOf(aOld.get(fieldName));
String newValue = String.valueOf(aNew.get(fieldName));


Alert_vod__c aht = new Alert_vod__c();

aht.Field_Names__c = fieldName;
aht.Name = 'Account Verified:'+ aNew.Name;
aht.Activation_Date_vod__c = date.today();
aht.Expiration_Date_vod__c = date.today().addDays(15);
aht.Dismissible_vod__c = true;
aht.Alert_Text_vod__c = fieldName + ' changed from '+ oldValue + ' to '+ newvalue;


apiNameList.add(aht.Field_Names__c);
fieldChanges.add(aht);
}        
}
}
}
}
if (!fieldChanges.isEmpty()) {
system.debug('@SN'+fieldChanges);
insert fieldChanges;
}
}
```

Comment: FYI CSS stands for [Cascading Style Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and is nothing to do with what you are looking for.

Comment: yes , I am sorry. Changed CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [SObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) can be used for interacting with an SObject that you may not know the type of at compile time. See the example below for a method that can take any SObject as a parameter. This method could be called from the different triggers on different objects.

```
static void process(List<SObject> sos) {
    for (SObject so : sos) {
        String name = so.get('Name');
        Schema.sObjectType soType = so.getSObjectType();
        so.put('Status__c', 'New Status');
    }
}
```

Examples of what your triggers could look like are shown below:

Custom Object:

```
trigger GenericTrigger on AnyObject__c (after update) { 
    TriggerHelper.process(Trigger.new);
}
```

Account Object:

```
trigger GenericTrigger on Account (after update) { 
    TriggerHelper.process(Trigger.new);
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks! I needed something like this. But what would be value of AnyObject__c?

Comment: I have put my trigger code in the question. Can you please let me know the change? Should I create another class for this?

Comment: AnyObject__c can be any custom or standard object. I have updated my answer to include two examples of the trigger

Comment: Thanks I have editted the question with my trigger. Can please do the change there?

Comment: This site is meant to help when you are stuck, it is not to ask people to do your work for you. My answer provides enough information to get you started on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Barcotter! I am working on this , this is what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggerHelper(Apex class) and place the logic there, then call methods of this class in triggers.